# Intervalo de valores dentro de um grupo biblioteca Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Estou tratando um conjunto de dados utilizando a biblioteca Pandas no python.

Agrupei meus dados em 4 grupos. Tenho a coluna dateTime (com data e hora) e quero saber o intervalo de tempo de cada grupo.

Aqui criei uma nova coluna com esse delta t:

```
df['deltaT'] = df.groupby('cycle').dateTime.max() - df.groupby('cycle').dateTime.min()
```

E me retorna uma lista com o intervalo de tempo de cada ciclo:

[image: E me retorna uma lista com o intervalo de tempo de cada ciclo:]

Porém, na tabela, a coluna deltaT ocupa as 4 primeiras linhas, e não os 4 grupos, que deveria ocupar.

O DataFrame de entrada seria:

```
|cycle|     dateTime    |
|0  |   25/11/2021 17:50|
|   |   25/11/2021 17:50|
|   |   25/11/2021 17:50|
|   |   25/11/2021 17:50|
|   |                   |
|...|       ...         |
|4  |   25/11/2021 17:58|
|   |   25/11/2021 17:58|
|   |   25/11/2021 17:58|
|   |   25/11/2021 17:58|
```

[image: dataframe entrada]

E a saida esperada é: Uma nova coluna contendo o tempo que levou cada ciclo. Ou seja, o `dateTime.max() - dateTime.min()` de cada ciclo (0,1,2,3,4).

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Olá gabreuneto, você poderia incluir um exemplo de dataframe de entrada (de preferência algo que seja facilmente copiável e colável, ou interpretável pela função `pd.read_clipboard()`) e o dado esperado como saída?

Comment: Olá, eu atualizei a pergunta. Sou bem novo nesse ramo, então me perdoa se da forma que postei não é interpretado pela função citada acima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html) para preservar a cardinalidade do seu DataFrame.

#### Criando DataFrame de exemplo:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (0,datetime(2021,12,1,10,0,1)),
        (0,datetime(2021,12,1,10,0,2)),
        (0,datetime(2021,12,1,10,0,3)),
        (0,datetime(2021,12,1,10,0,4)),
        (0,datetime(2021,12,1,10,0,5)),
        (1,datetime(2021,12,1,10,0,1)),
        (1,datetime(2021,12,1,10,1,2)),
        (1,datetime(2021,12,1,10,1,3)),
        (1,datetime(2021,12,1,10,1,4)),
        (1,datetime(2021,12,1,10,1,5)),
        (2,datetime(2021,12,1,10,0,1)),
        (2,datetime(2021,12,1,10,2,2)),
        (2,datetime(2021,12,1,10,2,3)),
        (2,datetime(2021,12,1,10,2,4)),
        (2,datetime(2021,12,1,10,2,5)),
        (3,datetime(2021,12,1,10,0,1)),
        (3,datetime(2021,12,1,10,3,2)),
        (3,datetime(2021,12,1,10,3,3)),
        (3,datetime(2021,12,1,10,3,4)),
        (3,datetime(2021,12,1,10,3,5)),
        (4,datetime(2021,12,1,10,0,1)),
        (4,datetime(2021,12,1,10,4,2)),
        (4,datetime(2021,12,1,10,4,3)),
        (4,datetime(2021,12,1,10,4,4)),
        (4,datetime(2021,12,1,10,4,5)),
    ], columns=["cycle","dateTime"]
)
df.to_markdown() #<-- usando o markdown de saída a seguir:
```

|  | cycle | dateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 2021-12-01 10:00:01 |
| 1 | 0 | 2021-12-01 10:00:02 |
| 2 | 0 | 2021-12-01 10:00:03 |
| 3 | 0 | 2021-12-01 10:00:04 |
| 4 | 0 | 2021-12-01 10:00:05 |
| 5 | 1 | 2021-12-01 10:00:01 |
| 6 | 1 | 2021-12-01 10:01:02 |
| 7 | 1 | 2021-12-01 10:01:03 |
| 8 | 1 | 2021-12-01 10:01:04 |
| 9 | 1 | 2021-12-01 10:01:05 |
| 10 | 2 | 2021-12-01 10:00:01 |
| 11 | 2 | 2021-12-01 10:02:02 |
| 12 | 2 | 2021-12-01 10:02:03 |
| 13 | 2 | 2021-12-01 10:02:04 |
| 14 | 2 | 2021-12-01 10:02:05 |
| 15 | 3 | 2021-12-01 10:00:01 |
| 16 | 3 | 2021-12-01 10:03:02 |
| 17 | 3 | 2021-12-01 10:03:03 |
| 18 | 3 | 2021-12-01 10:03:04 |
| 19 | 3 | 2021-12-01 10:03:05 |
| 20 | 4 | 2021-12-01 10:00:01 |
| 21 | 4 | 2021-12-01 10:04:02 |
| 22 | 4 | 2021-12-01 10:04:03 |
| 23 | 4 | 2021-12-01 10:04:04 |
| 24 | 4 | 2021-12-01 10:04:05 |

#### Incluindo a Coluna deltaT

```py
df['deltaT'] = df.groupby('cycle')['dateTime'].transform('max') - df.groupby('cycle')['dateTime'].transform('min')

df.to_markdown()
```

|  | cycle | dateTime | deltaT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 2021-12-01 10:00:01 | 0 days 00:00:04 |
| 1 | 0 | 2021-12-01 10:00:02 | 0 days 00:00:04 |
| 2 | 0 | 2021-12-01 10:00:03 | 0 days 00:00:04 |
| 3 | 0 | 2021-12-01 10:00:04 | 0 days 00:00:04 |
| 4 | 0 | 2021-12-01 10:00:05 | 0 days 00:00:04 |
| 5 | 1 | 2021-12-01 10:00:01 | 0 days 00:01:04 |
| 6 | 1 | 2021-12-01 10:01:02 | 0 days 00:01:04 |
| 7 | 1 | 2021-12-01 10:01:03 | 0 days 00:01:04 |
| 8 | 1 | 2021-12-01 10:01:04 | 0 days 00:01:04 |
| 9 | 1 | 2021-12-01 10:01:05 | 0 days 00:01:04 |
| 10 | 2 | 2021-12-01 10:00:01 | 0 days 00:02:04 |
| 11 | 2 | 2021-12-01 10:02:02 | 0 days 00:02:04 |
| 12 | 2 | 2021-12-01 10:02:03 | 0 days 00:02:04 |
| 13 | 2 | 2021-12-01 10:02:04 | 0 days 00:02:04 |
| 14 | 2 | 2021-12-01 10:02:05 | 0 days 00:02:04 |
| 15 | 3 | 2021-12-01 10:00:01 | 0 days 00:03:04 |
| 16 | 3 | 2021-12-01 10:03:02 | 0 days 00:03:04 |
| 17 | 3 | 2021-12-01 10:03:03 | 0 days 00:03:04 |
| 18 | 3 | 2021-12-01 10:03:04 | 0 days 00:03:04 |
| 19 | 3 | 2021-12-01 10:03:05 | 0 days 00:03:04 |
| 20 | 4 | 2021-12-01 10:00:01 | 0 days 00:04:04 |
| 21 | 4 | 2021-12-01 10:04:02 | 0 days 00:04:04 |
| 22 | 4 | 2021-12-01 10:04:03 | 0 days 00:04:04 |
| 23 | 4 | 2021-12-01 10:04:04 | 0 days 00:04:04 |
| 24 | 4 | 2021-12-01 10:04:05 | 0 days 00:04:04 |

Comment: Resolvido cara, muito obrigado! Ajudou muito :D